# Facebook page not auto resizing to smaller content

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Here is the Facebook page in aciton](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Troubadour-TX-testing-page/187889564610859?sk=app_258322430848282)

[Here's the page in Wordpress](http://troubadourtx.goldenspiralcreative.com/?page=fbindex)

So I'm creating a Wordpress-based Facebook page and I've got the proper code to automatically resize the built in iFrame that Facebook uses, but if you go to the artists page, scroll to the bottom and select one of the last artists, the iFrame will not only not resize, but it also won't scroll to the top.  I've tried just about everything, does anyone have any ideas?  Keep in mind, since I'm using Wordpress, I have the header and footer loading every individual Facebook PHP page in between.  So I'm not entirely sure if it's loading the header and footer every single page change (then again, it might be, I'm not sure), which could explain why it would resize bigger, but not smaller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a links to any pages. Only a video and bg image.

Comment: @Gthompson83: Sorry about that, I was putting a like script up, which is why you only saw the like page.  Please try again, I've temporarily reversed the liking script.

Comment: Have you tried using [`FB.Canvas.setSize();`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/) instead?

Comment: @ifaour: Yes, I have, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FB.Canvas.scrollTo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/)

So it turns out that I wasn't calling scrollTo correctly earlier.  And while my iFrame won't necessarily resize back up, I am able to scroll back up to the top, which aesthetically is acceptable for me.  It may not be for your project, but it will at least fix it within my desire.